# How to send message with telegram inline bots

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have set my webhook and it gives me updates, but I don't know how to send `InlineQueryResult` with `php`

I want to send a text like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc
```

How can I send it with php curl? This is what I am currentry trying:

```
$token = 'bot###';
$chat_id = '###';

$keyboardl = ['inline_keyboard' => [[['text' =>  "one", 'callback_data' => "1"],['text' =>  "two", 'callback_data' => "2"]]]];

$data = array("chat_id" => $chat_id,"results" => "??????","reply_markup" => $keyboardl);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/'.$token.'/answerinlinequery');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

}
```

I dont know which [InlineQueryResult](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresult) I have to use in order to send text.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude :  how to send answer with answerinlinequery

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude : i dont know what to send in result : $data = array("chat_id" => $chat_id,"results" => "??????","reply_markup" => $keyboardl);

Comment: Please, tell me from where did you copy this code (give me the URL) and I will try to help you

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude :  I ve created it my own....can you give me a tutorial site for create inline bot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To send a text with InlineQuery you need to use `InlineQueryResultArticle` [(doc)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultarticle) and therefore set the type to `article`. 
You don't need to set the `chat_id` since the data automatically gets sent in the current active chat. It gets identified via the `inline_query_id` which corresponds to the `id` you receive in the `InlineQuery`.

```
$results = array();

$entry = array(
    "type" => "article", 
    "id" => "1", 
    "title" => "Title", 
    "description" => "Description", 
    "input_message_content" => array("message_text" => "Text to be sent")
);

array_push($results, $entry);

$post = array(
    "inline_query_id" => $queryId, 
    "results" => json_encode($results)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/answerInlineQuery");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I have question: What should be `inline_query_id` value? I couldn't find any more description in [Tg Bot Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answerinlinequery).

Comment: That's the `id` you receive along with the other `InlineQuery` Information. [(InlineQuery)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery). You just need to pass it back.

Comment: thanks+1. Really I have no view on this type of inline messaging. I have a bot with inline keyboard and add your code to one of my keys and get `"ok"="true"` response from telegram but no changes happen on my telegram api? What should i expect on my TG api?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but since this question isn't about  inline keyboard I guess you should make a new question.